# PackageReference Aliases are ignored on parent projects

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Actually I'm trying to use the two libraries [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/) and [Microsoft.Graph.Beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/) in parallel within my solution.

To get this to work, you can use aliases within references. For this purpose you first have to write within your `.csproj` file something like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.25.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Beta" Version="4.40.0-preview">
  <Aliases>GraphBeta</Aliases>    
</PackageReference>
```

After that within your `.cs` file at the top you can write something like this:

```
extern alias GraphBeta;
using Beta = GraphBeta.Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph;
```

And within your code you can access both parts individually like this:

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(new HttpClient());
var betaClient = new Beta.GraphServiceClient(new HttpClient());
```

So far so good.

Unfortunately within my solution I'm using the above code within a *library project*. This *library project* is referenced by my *application project* and within my *application project* I also need to make some calls to `Microsoft.Graph` only. After adding the beta package to my *library project* I'm getting compiler errors from my *application project* like this:

```
error CS0433: The type 'IMessageAttachmentsCollectionPage' exists in both 'Microsoft.Graph.Beta, Version=4.40.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.Graph, Version=4.25.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

So it seems, the given alias to the NuGet package within my *library project* doesn't flow upwards to my *application project*. My *application project* doesn't have any direct reference to any of the both Graph libraries, it just consumes it through the indirect dependency from the *library project*.

Also trying to add the `extern alias` line to the file within my *application project* results in this error message:

```
error CS0430: The extern alias 'GraphBeta' was not specified in a /reference option
```

Any solution available to either make the alias flowing upwards to my *application project* or to make the Beta dependency *internal* to the *library project*?

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot.

It's weird that the Beta documentation says this:

"The Beta library is generated with the Microsoft.Graph.Beta namespace. This means that it can be used alongside the V1 package by using the Microsoft.Graph namespace while using the Microsoft.Graph.Beta namespace from the beta library."

Comment: The described behavior was true for v4. Since v5 the official and beta libraries are using different namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

After some further try-and-error, my current solution is to add a reference to the `Graph.Beta` assembly (including the alias) explicitly to the *application project*. After that the error message is gone.

But this is just a simplified example. In my real project I have a deeper structure of multiple library projects and now every project that needs to use the Microsoft.Graph namespace needs to get an explicit package reference with the alias to the Beta package. For example if you have a *test project* for your *library project*, it must explicitly reference the Beta package including the alias if it tries to use any type from the Microsoft.Graph namespace within a test.